# Classify pandas dataframe based on another using string contains

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data frames - one with raw data, another with a mapping/classifier for the raw data.  I want to iterate thru the raw data and return the classifications based on the other one.

df =

```
Artist  Genres  Image   Popularity  Followers       Americana   Around the World    BritRock    ... Pops    Post-Punk / Angular Progressive Psych'  Punky   Shoegazer / Dreamer Soul / Funk Soundtracks Younger Rap Younget Indie
0   0   Buke and Gase   [brooklyn indie, deep indie rock]   https://i.scdn.co/image/eece57650f99d1265f871a...   32  9328                    ...                                     
1   0   Bright Light Bright Light   [austindie] https://i.scdn.co/image/5234fdee902fe1d4d5ad20...   39  23153                   ...                                     
2   0   Angelo De Augustine [preverb, small room]   https://i.scdn.co/image/3080e9d856e639d539804b...   45  6393                    ...                                     
3   0   Modeselektor    [alternative dance, electronic, indietronica, ...   https://i.scdn.co/image/1bf7a85bcc0c047d8914a2...   50  120084                  ...                                     
4   0   Razorlight  [britpop, garage rock, indie rock, modern rock...   https://i.scdn.co/image/b743a5f809f671be6a60f7...   63  252969                  ...                                     
5 rows × 33 columns
```

classifier:

```
spotify_genre   class_one
0   21st century classical  Peaceful Music
1   abstract    Conscious Hip-Hop
2   abstract hip hop    Conscious Hip-Hop
3   abstractro  Experimental / Noise / Drone
4   acid house  Mature Dance Head
```

I want to iterate on df['Genres'] and where any strings hit a partial match against classifier['spotify_genre'] then it should return a count of 1 to the necessary column in df as decided by classifier['class_one'] 
Eg Buke and Gase has a genre 'brooklyn indie' that should return a '1' for 'Younger Indie' column in the original df.

I've tried loads of different ways to tackle the problem but can't figure out the best approach.

Comment: You need to include a minimal reproducible example of your problem. Do not include dataframes with `...`, as this is likely necessary information.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this in 2 steps. first use a dict to map the values into a single column in your original df:

```
df['class'] = df['Genres'].map(dict)
```

where dict is a dictionary in the format

```
dict = {'abstract': 'Conscious Hip-Hop', 'abstract hip hop': 'Conscious Hip-Hop', #...
```

Then you can use `pandas.get_dummies()` on `df['class']` to get all the columns you want.